# Possible To Select AMIs When Launching an AWS Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm doing a few machine learning courses and using an Amazon AWS p2.xlarge instance. The instance and the AMI were configured by the instructors of one of the courses. Now I need to run another AMI for a different course. Is it possible to launch this new AMI on the existing Instance.

I don't want to run multiple instances because I only need to launch one of the AMIs at any time. Is there a way to pick which AMI to launch when starting a stopped instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not change the AMI of a running instance.

We may describe an AWS AMI as a collection of snapshots, that's only relevant starting your instance.

You may create new instances, if you want to use a distinct AMI.